# How do I get multiple identical href links from identical elements

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping data about fitness classes and writing it to a csv file. On the webpage i'm trying to scrape the class name, description, address, contact number, website and social links. I'm using `BeautifulSoup` and `Selenium`.

Here is a link to the page: https://classpass.com/classes/stretch-london-ada-street/strong-flow-yoga/322325148#tabs?search-id=40447186987779531

The elements looks like this:

```
<a class="_2MTzNd_HEKWjVL824SA9Li" href="https://instagram.com/stretch_london"
```

It is the same for all the different socials with the only difference being the url within the element.

I've been able to use the method below to get the other non href data I want from the page i.e class name, description etc. and write to csv:

```
        try:
            class_name = classses_soup.find('span', {'data-component': 'LocalizableMessage'}).text
        except (AttributeError, TypeError,) as e:
            pass
```

However I can't get the href links, I think because they are all identical elements? So for example, the code below is not working - the extract below is for the instagram link but i have an identical line of code for facebook and twitter:

```
try:
    instagram = classses_soup.find('a', {'class': '_2MTzNd_HEKWjVL824SA9Li'}).a.href
except (AttributeError, TypeError, IndexError,) as e:
    pass
```

It gives the following error:

```
NameError: name "class_wesbite" is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I get my code to scrape each link so that I can write to csv like it does with the other elements?

Answer (score 1):

Hi below code gets the social media links as per your page:-

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from functools import partial  
from operator import is_not

links = []
filter_null = partial(filter, partial(is_not, None))

url = "https://classpass.com/classes/stretch-london-ada-street/strong-flow-yoga/322325148#tabs?search-id=40447186987779531"  # no trailing /
try:
    page = requests.get(url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

    last_links = soup.find("div", {"id": "find-us-social-links"})

    artist_name_list_items = last_links.find_all('a')
    for artist_name in artist_name_list_items:

        links.append(artist_name.get('href'))
        L =list(filter_null(links))
    print(links)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    print("continuing....")
```

Comment: Can you add a quick explanation?

Comment: sure the trick actually is to find the links after getting into the right HTML element.
For example, in this case, "find-us-social-links" is the id of the div which stores the weblinks

Comment:  And just a kind suggestion: You help a lot with good code. I think your answers would be even more valuable if you always added some short explanation.

Comment: Thanks :) and will definitely try to add answers with more explanation further!